# React Native: Reference to pod still present after running `yarn remove`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, yarnpkg

I'm trying to get a legacy React Native project running, and removed `react-native-sharing-winstagram` with `yarn remove react-native-sharing-winstagram`. I get the following error:

```
[!] The `RNReactNativeSharingWinstagram` pod failed to validate due to 1 error:
    - ERROR | attributes: Missing required attribute `homepage`.
    - WARN  | source: The version should be included in the Git tag.
    - WARN  | description: The description is equal to the summary.
```

I've seen other posts where people address similar error messages, but not when the package was supposed to have been removed. Is there something additional that I should do in order to remove reference to a pod?``

Comment: Can you try running pod deintegrate and then pod install again?

Comment: What happens when you navigate to ios folder and run pod install command?

Comment: To clarify, `pod install` is what throws the error. When I do `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`, I still get the same error. I can confirm that there are no traces of react-native-sharing-winstagram in package.json or yarn.lock

Comment: does pod update fix something ?

Comment: @Imasneri I can't run `pod update` until I successfully run `pod install`. It throws an error telling me this.